# Is there a way to cast spells with a range of self on other targets?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I have a number of spells like expeditious retreat or false life that have a range of self that would work better if I could cast them on other characters. Is there a feat, class feature or anything else for wizard that enables you to do that?

Comment: In order to make the answers more useful, could you indicate what sorts of spells you wish to use and whether the recipient needs to be willing? In general, a "Self" spell does not include rules for attack rolls or saves, which are usually necessary when casting spells that affect others. Also, does it need to be specifically  "a feat or class feature choice for wizard", or could magic items or multi classing address your problem?

Comment: Edited with clarifications.

Comment: First, be John Malkovich, then have your friend be John Malkovich. Then cast the spell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Items of Spell Storage.

A rings (or other items) of storage can be the target of any spell.  The spell is cast into the ring and whoever wears it later can cast the spell as if they cast it.  It requires owning/crafting this particular type of magic item, but it is a good work around.

### Crafting.

The DMG has optional rules for creating a magical item, and it includes casting the spell on an object over a period of time.  If you DM allows crafting, you have the downtime and the money, you could craft an item with the effect of allowing someone else to cast your spell with range of self. This is an optional rule, is a costly and time consuming process, but in some cases might make the world of difference.

Comment: +1 for the simplest and most workable solution, i.e. [Ring] of Spell Storing.

Comment: You really don't need to incorporate information from other answers into your own, it only makes clutter/duplicate info on the page. -1 Also, the spell storing answers a broader question "how to make effects of <self> spells available to others" but the one Q above is a narrower one.

Comment: Technically, the question in the title is a different question than the one in the body of the text ("way", vs, "feat or class feature choice"). It's unclear which the asker would find more useful.

Answer (score 7):

You can use *magic jar* to get into the body of your friend, then cast the spell, finally go back to your own body.

The method has various disadvantages, although it can work:

1. Magic jar is a lvl6 spell.
2. It may require to bypass the defenses of your friends, even if they are willing.
3. It belongs to the school of necromancy and manipulates souls, so a paladin might have a problem with that.
4. In most cases it is DM's discretion if he allows this. Maybe a new question could be interesting about the interaction of self-targeted spells and magic jar. I would sometimes allow it, sometimes wouldn't. Most probably I wouldn't ever allow to control of the spell for your friend.

Comment: I've altered the statement about paladins, necromancy, and alignment to not state it as a fact (it isn't in 5e), but as a possible objection. Hopefully that addresses the issue and there's no more need to debate in comments, but if there are still issues with it, then I guess comments will let us know!

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, but only in a really specific way**

The 2nd level Paladin spell *Find Steed* says:

> While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast that targets only
>   you also target your steed.

So *if* you take 5 levels of Paladin and *if* you are happy that the only additional creature affected is your steed then this is an option.

Other then that, you can't do this AFAIK.

Clearly the designers have made some spells target *Self* for a reason.

Comment: The question specifies "wizard" and does not mention multi classing.

Answer (score 3):

## Glyph of Warding

Spells with the range of 'self' obviously target a single creature (at least, most of the time) and so are eligible for placement in a *Glyph of Warding*.  The *Glyph* overrides the spell's normal targeting and range and so on and (in this case) makes the spell target the creature that triggered the *Glyph*.

*Glyph of Warding* **also** overrides concentration requirements, which is extremely useful for many spells that have a range of Self and lets you stack buffs if you feel so inclined.  It also can store any level of spell you have the slots to cast, even spells of its own level and even another *Glyph of Warding*.  Basically, it's just the best spell ever, and your wizard should be learning it anyways, and it does what you want.

The only downside is the gp cost which, at 200 gp/cast, is pretty high.  Be careful in choosing the fights you wish to use this for.

Comment: Bonus points if the spell you store is *Contact Other Plane*.  It's a DC 15 INT save or die.  That's a better-than-even chance of forcing even an Ancient Red Dragon to waste a legendary resistance. Given how many players dump INT, it's also a killer trap.